Technique for traveling through a dictionary
Given a dictionary where the keys hold coordinates and the values hold a list of possible values, how to output a list of all the dictionaries that can be created with a single value taken from each list?
input = {(0, 0): [1, 2], (0, 1): [3, 4]}

output = [{(0, 0): 1, (0, 1): 3}, {(0, 0): 1, (0, 1): 4}, {(0, 0): 2, (0, 1): 3}, {(0, 0): 2, (0, 1): 4}]

Note: The method must be able to handle a dictionary with lists of unequal size and None values (the case where values are None can be skipped), e.g.
{(0, 0): [1, 2], (0, 1): [3, 4], (1, 0): [5, 6, 7], (1, 1): None}

Sketch of loop | maybe not the right approach?
def loop(input):
    """return a lits of dictionaries that store every coordinate/value pair among the dictionary of candidate values"""
    # initialize a list to hold all the dictionaries
    lst = []
    # initialize dictionary to hold coordinate/value pairs
    dct = {}
    for key, values in input.items(): 
        for v in values:
            # what can I do here? 
            if key not in dct:
                # check dct to enforce uniqueness?
                kv = {key: v}
                dct.update(kv)
    if dct not in lst:
        lst.append(dct)
    return lst
loop(input)
# [{(0, 0): 1, (0, 1): 3}, {(0, 0): 1, (0, 1): 4}, {(0, 0): 2, (0, 1): 3}, {(0, 0): 2, (0, 1): 4}]

Also, as I travel through the dictionary, how do I make sure that I pick all combinations? How can I enforce an order?

Are elements with value == None supposed to be ignored? If not, how do they contribute to the result?

I think itertools.product() will be useful for this.

This question is similar to: Cartesian product of a dictionary of lists. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

What output do you expect for input {(0, 0): [1, 2], (0, 1): []}?

Like None the empty list can be discarded. Because I create these lists from None, I never actually end up with an empty list. However, if I did, I would just discard it. And to answer your question, I'd expect just [{(0, 0): 1}, {(0, 0): 2}]. My current problem is more one of abundance than scarcity though! :-)

A question with a title like "Cartesian product of" is useful only inasmuch as you know that you're looking for the "Cartesian product". Since I didn't know that, I didn't hit on that question. It could be useful now, but it wasn't useful then.

First remove null values:
>>> input_ = {(0, 0): [1, 2], (0, 1): [3, 4]}
>>> d = {k: v for k, v in input_.items() if v}

Then just zip up elements from the product:
>>> from itertools import product
>>> for p in product(*d.values()):
...     print(dict(zip(d, p)))
... 
{(0, 0): 1, (0, 1): 3}
{(0, 0): 1, (0, 1): 4}
{(0, 0): 2, (0, 1): 3}
{(0, 0): 2, (0, 1): 4}


Excellent, thanks @wim. I see that itertools has a lot of useful functions. I'm going to take a closer look at the docs. itertools.product calculates the "cartesian product, equivalent to a nested for-loop". See: https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html
